# Classification of glycosidic anomeric bonds (alpha vs. beta)

Tags: biochemistry, homework

In the process of studying for my upcoming biochemistry exam, I have stumbled over the classification of glycosidic bonds. I want to be able to distinguish $\alpha$- from $\beta$-glycosidic bonds. Unfortunately, even after reading through [this](http://www.chem.qmul.ac.uk/iupac/2carb/06n07.html) page, I don't really understand how to go about classifying the bonds in e.g. an oligosaccharide.

[image: Oligosaccharide]
([Source](http://www.elicityl-oligotech.com/client/cache/produit/500_______GLY058-AP_253.jpg))

Now, I am inclined to say that both of these anomeric linkages are of type $\alpha$, because the O-glycosidic bond is axial to the respective sugar rings. Is that a correct way of reasoning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my interpretation, as far as I can get, which agrees with your deduction that both of the *O*-glycosidic bonds involve α epimers. (If the epimeric carbon has an -OH in the axial direction then this is the α anomer.)

Do you have the name of this compound?

Let's hope that a real glycobiologist comes along.

**Supplementary**
I'm now not sure that it is even possible to assign an anomeric state to the sugar marked as ?. There is no indication in the diagram of the presence of a -CH<sub>2</sub>OH substituent on the ring - it appears to have a methyl group instead. If that group **was** a -CH<sub>2</sub>OH then the putative anomeric C would indeed be in the α form since it is pointing in the opposite direction from the "-CH<sub>2</sub>OH" (c.f. the two galactose residues). If ? is a deoxy- derivative of a sugar then it may be that the convention still holds.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a name for the compound, I just grabbed an image from the internet that looked roughly like the exam problem I was trying to solve.